# pyautogui sometimes doesn't switch windows in the following code

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm using this function to switch windows, to simulate Alt + Tab:

```
import time
import pyautogui

def switch_windows():
    pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
    pyautogui.press('tab')
    pyautogui.keyUp('alt')
```

It works most of the time. But sometimes I get stuck in the terminal and a `^[` characters appears:

```
alex@alex-M52AD-M12AD-A-F-K31AD:~/bash/s6-auto$ python3 script.py                                   
^[
```

What could be the reason, and how to fix this?

Comment: Try another library like `keyboard`, will the error show up?

Comment: Focus can be at this moment not on the window, but on another element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the context manager:

```
with pyautogui.hold('alt'):
    pyautogui.press('tab')
```

or shortcut keys:

```
pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'tab')
```

[documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#keyboard-keys)